# Stata: ignore missing values when counting

Tags: stata

I'd like to create a variable (*counter*) which counts non-missing values of another variable (*firmage0*) in every year. My code looks like this:

```
sort year  
quietly by year: gen counter = _n if firmage0 != .
```

Unfortunately, Stata starts counting with 1 even if there are missing values. But I'd like to start counting when there is a non-missing value. In addition the second nonmissing value should have the value "2", the third "3" and so on. There is one important restriction. Don't use **preserve** and **restore**! After creating the variable *counter*, my dataset looks like this (this is only a small part of it). Free space means missing value!

```
year    firmage0    counter
1975        
1975        
1975        
1975        
1975    21  5
1975        
1975    60  7
1975        
1975        
1975        
1975        
1975        
1975        
1975        
1975        
1975        
1975        
1975        
1975        
1975    115 20
1975        
1975        
1975
```

But the dataset should look like this:

```
year    firmage0    counter
1975        
1975        
1975        
1975        
1975    21  1
1975        
1975    60  2
1975        
1975        
1975        
1975        
1975        
1975        
1975        
1975        
1975        
1975        
1975        
1975        
1975    115 3
1975        
1975        
1975
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system variable `_n` is *fixed* in the sense that it denotes the number of the current observation independently of your `if` condition. What you are asking for with your code is a `counter` that takes on the value of the number of the observation *if* it is not missing. This is different from the count of non-missing observations up until a certain point, which is what you really want.

Be aware of the 
data type of your *missings*. As you present it, `firmage0` seems like a string variable because
blanks are missings for strings. Missings for numeric values are
represented as `.` (or `.<something>`). See `help missings`.

One solution is doing a cumulative `sum` conditional on the `missings`. I assume variable type is numeric:

```
clear all
set more off

input year firmage0
1975      .  
1975      . 
1975      .      
1975      .  
1975    21
1980    60 
1980    .
1980    89       
1985      . 
1985      .  
1985    23    
1985    45    
1985    47
1985     .   
end 

list, sepby(year)

bysort year: gen counter = sum(!missing(firmage0))
replace counter = . if missing(firmage0) // optional

list, sepby(year)
```

`!missing(firmage0)` evaluates to false (0) or true (1) depending on whether the observation for `firmage0` is missing or not, respectively. Then `sum` does the cumulative sum of that.

If the variable is in fact of string type, then replace the corresponding line with:

```
replace counter = "" if missing(firmage0) // optional
```

A one-liner (for numeric type) is:

```
bysort year: gen counter = cond(missing(firmage0), ., sum(!missing(firmage0)))
```

but I prefer the first way because it is easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that if you sort by `year` and `firmage0` before:

```
. sort year firmage0
```

you will have your problem solved. I changed the year of one of the `firmage0` values just to confirm that it would restart the count.

```
. by year : gen counter = _n if firmage0 !=.

year    firmage0    counter               
1975    21  1     
1975    60  2   
1975        
1975        
1975        
1975        
1975        
1975        
1975        
1975        
1975        
1975        
1975        
1975        
1975        
1975        
1975        
1975        
1975        
1975        
1975        
1975        
1976    115 1
```

Comment: Consider using `!missing(firmage0)` instead of `firmage0 !=.` to generalize to both string and numeric types.

Comment: This is risky in so far as your previous `sort` order won't be restorable reliably without extra code.